# overlay is not working in IE6?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, overlay

Iam using the following code in my file for overlay image.This works fine in firefox but not in IE6.Can anyone please suggest a solution for this??

```
<div id="1" onclick="document.getElementById('div1').className = 'nodis';" CLASS="nodis" style="width:100%; background:url('/gifs/overlay.png');" align="center">
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do and what doesn't it do?

Comment: this is opening up an image in blow up mode with an overlay grey image.When i open this image in FF its works fine and displays the overlay image but doesnot completely hide the content over which the image is displayed.While in IE6 the overlay image completely hides the background content of the page and only shows the image.I want that overlay should work like an overlay i.e. it should not completely hide the page's content with its image.I want my overlay image to be transparent sort of.I hope my problem is clear now.

Comment: So you're simply asking about everyones favorite topic of [transparency support for PNG images in IE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Web_browser_support_for_PNG).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have misunderstood your question, but here is a solution for PNG fix using javascript: [PNGFix](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bobosola/pnghowto.htm). If this is not what you need, please correct me and give me more detailed explanation or link to your site.

Comment: thanks your link helped me as i picked that filter thing from it and have implemented on my code.

Comment: Glad I hepled. Have in mind that there are also other solutions for this issue, for instance http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6

Answer (score 2):

Png overlays aren't supported in IE6, and you'll have to make use of [other hacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Web_browser_support_for_PNG)* instead.

**Or**, you could do what Microsoft has already done: **drop support for IE6**.

Microsoft are pushing out IE8 as a critical security update, so even Windows users that have pirated windows copies will get automatic upgrades from IE6. And large corporations aren't an issue anymore, since very few IT departments in the world want to have unsupported 3rd party software under their responsibility.

If you're *still* worried that many of your users use IE6, and you want to make sure they can see the page correctly, make use of an update script such as [IE6update](http://www.ie6update.com), which will tell your users that they need a browser update to show your page correctly.

*) Thanks to [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/476/deceze) for the link to various hacks.

Comment: A lot of Web Developers follow the [Yahoo Graded Browser Support](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/tutorials/gbs/) Baseline, as they believe there is still enough of a market using IE6 to warrant its support.